# How to compare the values of same index in multiple list and print the start time and end time if condition not satisfy?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

Here, i have 6 lists, all of them has same length of data. one is time which contains time from one start point to one end point and another five list contains signals.

```
    time = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67]
    A  =   [0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    B =    [0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
    C =    [0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    D =    [0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
    E =    [0,  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Here first i want to compare list **A** and **B**. if in list **A**  0  comes and in the same index 2 comes in **B** and if it is True then in second condition  check in the same index in other three list there **C** should be 0, **D** should be 0 and **E** should be 1. if this condition satisfy then it is passed but in case in some point it comes different value then i need the start time and end time.

```
or j in range(len(time)):
lis = []
lis2 = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    if(A[i] == 0 and B[i] == 2):
        if C == 0 and D == 0 and E == 1:
            lis.append(time[i])
        else:
            lis2.append(time[i])

 print lis
 print lis2
```

Using this code i've got the time where it is not satisfying but this isn't what i want.
i want the start time and end time like this

```
OUTPUT - [33,42] or [33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42]
```

Because in this time period 1st condition is True and from where it fails 2nd condition from there it should print the time till 1st condition True like i've given in output, then no need to check further.

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: why till 42, when pattern is only till 40?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
or j in range(len(time)):
lis = []
lis2 = []
bool = false
for i in range(len(A)):
    if bool:
        break
    if(A[i] == 0 and B[i] == 2):
        if C == 0 and D == 0 and E == 1:
            lis.append(time[i])
        else:
            bool = true
            lis2.append(time[i])

print lis
print lis2
```

Comment: thank you. but this is not the answer what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(A)
B = np.array(B)
C = np.array(C)
D = np.array(D)
E = np.array(E)
time = np.array(time)

print time[(A == 0)*(B == 2)*(C == 0)*(D == 0)*(E == 1)]
```

By the way, your example is wrong. The correct result is `[32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]`, thus there are two periods with the correct pattern (from 31 to 40 and from 48 to 52).

Comment: No, i want to print only from 33 to 42, because as you can see in the time of 33 2nd condition has failed. and why till 42 because 1st condition is True consecutively till 42

Comment: what you have written that is giving where all 5 condition is satisfying which i was getting  through my code but i want in my code where my 1st condition is True and 2nd is False. from that point i've to print the time till 1st condition True consecutively

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want all the periods where either condition is true, where at least the first element of a period satisfies both conditions? Why isn't [48,52] a valid period as well?